# how to configure CircleCI with custom yml or existing orb to release to github packages

Tags: java, circleci, maven-release-plugin, github-packages, circleci-orb

Looking for existing solution to be able to release a java library to github packages, currently Im able to deploy(with snapshot) but now i want to be able to release a new version, this is the existing command in circleCI config " command: mvn release:prepare release:perform -DskipTests -s .circleci/settings.xml -f pom.xml"
but keeps getting "[ERROR] ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only." even tho I have a deploy key with write access, seems like some how the config is not able to pick up the correct key to perform the commit back to github repo, I was wondering if there is a more standard solution using an existing ORB, or some example i can take a look at.

Thanks in advance.

I already try this [one](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/sonatype-nexus-community/circleci-maven-release-orb) but its not quite what i need, that ORB is trying to configure a GPG key which i dont think i need that.